# Using IMDB-API and when I make a call I am not receiving anything back

Tags: c#, api, imdb

I am writing a program using the IMDB web api (https://imdb-api.com/) however when I am making a call with it I am not receiving any data back, I have reached out to them a few weeks ago but still not heard any response. The apiKey is correct and part of another function.

Below is the api I call I am making:

```
private void SearchForMovie()
{
        string hostURL = "https://imdb-api.com/eng/API/SearchMovie/" +apiKey+ "/" + Searchbar.Text;

        WebRequest wrGETURL;

        wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(hostURL);

        Stream objStream;
        objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);

        string jsonData = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        searchData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchData>(jsonData);

        

        MessageBox.Show(searchResult.Id);
}
```

And this is the .Json file that on there website said I should use:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SearchData
{
  public string SearchType { get; set; }
  public string Expression { get; set; }

  public List<SearchResult> Results { get; set; }

  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResult
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string ResultType { get; set; }
  public string Image { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

public enum SearchType
{
  Title = 1,
  Movie = 2,
  Series = 4,
  Name = 8,
  Episode = 16,
  Company = 32,
  Keyword = 64,
  All = 128
}
```

Comment: If not data, what are you receiving back? Do you have any exception handling or logging?

Comment: Their documentation shows "en" for english language. Is that what you meant instead of "eng"?

Comment: @Crowcoder I do not have any exception handling, I am just trying to get it to display the title id in the messagebox, however it is coming back as an Exception Thrown message with "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
searchResult was null." Which I am assuming is because the call is not receiving any data back.
I have been using Hannah as an example and when pasted into the web I get this :

Comment: {"searchType":"Movie","expression":"hannah","results":[{"id":"tt0126321","resultType":"Title","image":"https://imdb-api.com/images/original/MV5BMjA1NjY4MzU3MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjk2MzU1MQ@@._V1_Ratio0.7273_AL_.jpg","title":"The Girl","description":"(1996) (TV Movie) aka \"Hannah\""},

Comment: If you debug, what is the value of `searchData` before you open the message box? You may need to [compensate for camel case of json.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm)